# Checking boxes with associated with HABTM in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, associations

So, I have models associated via HABTM. In one view, I'm using checkboxes to save associations. I can save data no problem. But what I can't determine is how cleanly check boxes of pre-existing associations, say, when I go onto an Edit page and want to edit associations.

In this case, I have a User model and a Survey model.

Here's the code for my view:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $this->Form->input('User.User.', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'value' => $user['User']['id'], 'hiddenField' => false, 'label' => false )) . ' ' . $user['User']['username'];
}
```

There must be a way to simply mark boxes as selected where appropriate.

Comment: `'selected' => true`? Is this so existing records don't get deleted? If you're using cake2.0 there's a new feature that allows you to keep them, search the book, I forgot what its called.

Comment: So they won't get deleted but so selections can be changed. That means users need to be presented with current selections from the db. Setting "checked => true" isn't the problem, it's cleanly looping over the records to assign it where required.